# android 5.0.1 emulator stopping the app

Tags: android, emulation

I am using android 5.0.1 api level 21.My emulator is being launched fine,but when i try to run my app on it,it just opens it up and suddenly gives the message
"app is unfortunately stopped". What should i do?

Comment: "what should I do?" Read the logcat output and find the stacktrace.

Comment: can you please help me with that? i am a newbie.

Comment: post your logcat output , to find out the exact problem

Comment: it's just showing "Device disconnected: 1"

Comment: here is my logcat file: